# PostgreSQL - Backup and Restore Database Tables with Partitions

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, dump

I'm working on PostgreSQL 8.4 and I'd like to do backup and restore (from Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 12.4)

I want to include all partitions, clusters, roles and stuff.

My commands:
Back up:

```
dumb_all > filename
```

Compress:

```
zip -f mybackup
```

Uncompress and restore:

```
sudo gunzip -c /home/ubuntu/Desktop/backupFile.zip | psql -U postgres
```

The issue is in the restore process, I got an error

```
invalid command \.
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2"
LINE 1: 2 2 1
        ^
invalid command \.
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 1: ...
        ^
out of memory
```

Plus, the tables with partitions did not restored. also some tables restored without any data!

Please help!

**EDIT**

I used pgAdmin to do the back up, using the "backup server" option.

[image: backup]

Comment: You could post here the commands that you **really** used, as the problem may reside on them... Seriously, just copy and paste here...

Comment: I added some details and I changed the compress command

Comment: How about the restore, how did you do? After pgAdmin have you compressed the result? How?

Comment: the same commands in the question. I did the backup using `dump_all` then compressed the result using `zip -f mybackup` then uncompressed and restored it in another DB using one command `sudo gunzip -c /home/ubuntu/Desktop/backupFile.zip | psql -U postgres` Do you have a better method?

Comment: No, you didn't!!! How `zip -f mybackup` would generate a file named `backupFile.zip`? Anyway, I think I guessed your problem, see my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did used `zip` to compress the output, then you should use `unzip` do uncompress it, not `gunzip`, they use different formats/algorithms.

I'd suggest you to use `gzip` and `gunzip` only. For instance, if you generated a backup named `mybackup.sql`, you can gzip it with:

```
gzip mybackup.sql
```

It will generate a file named `mybackup.sql.gz`. Then, to restore, you can use:

```
gunzip -c mybackup.sql.gz | psql -U postgres
```

Also, I'd suggest you to avoid using pgAdmin to do the dump. Not that it can't do, it is just that you can't automatize it, you can easily use `pg_dumpall` the same way:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres -f mybackup.sql
```

You can either dump and compress without intermediate files using pipe:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres | gzip -c > mybackup.sql.gz
```

BTW, I'd really suggest you avoiding `pg_dumpall` and use `pg_dump` with custom format for each database, as with that you already get the result compressed and easier to use latter. But `pg_dumpall` is ok for small databases.

Comment: @Shadin @MetheusOl I have tried all suggestions above but still an error.
    

`gzip: /users/srv-postgresql/backup/bmipgsqld1-testdb-2016-05-31-23-00-05.psql.gz: Permission denied`

Comment: @kjosh: your problem is permission on the OS for the user you are running the backup. I suggest create a new question if you want more help on that.